# Which tags should I use on question about "version tracking"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

In the spirit of [this thread](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-subject), I would like to know if I tagged [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/829/241) correctly.

I've tagged it as `security-awareness`, as I think being aware of major updates and security issues of piece of software one is dependant is a good way to be able to know and mitigate security risks oneself. As an after-thought, I thought about using the tag `best-practice`. In the end, I'm not sure either is either qualified, and maybe a new tag is needed, but I couldn't say which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... That's a tough one, since in truth I don't expect there to be as many questions around that.
I think `awareness` was a good choice, `best-practice` seems generic enough for most questions (I'm not really sure what it is even meant to cover).
Perhaps another tag around `updates` or `patching` would be appropriate, but as I said I don't foresee many questions filling this tag (except for maybe around OS-updates, but still not a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting coincidence, since that is the first question I re-tagged after earning the ability to do so.

I added these: tools known-vulnerabilities java.
Perhaps a new one for "development" would make sense and be widely applicable.